# Spring cloud-config client giving error Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified

Tags: java, git, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

1. Spring cloud-config server started with application.properties :

```
server.port:8888
spring.application.name=test-config-server
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://gitlab.com/pearsontechnology/gpt/sms/sms-micro-services/config-server.git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=develop

#Private repo. access credentials
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=xxx
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=xxxx

spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.cloud.config.profile=dev
```

On starting the config-client,
*Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.*

My version of spring boot, spring-cloud and dependencies are as follows from pom.xml :

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
<java.version>17</java.version>
<spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

application.prop of config-client :

```
spring.application.name=systems-lookup-service
spring.cloud.config.profile=dev
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:
server.port=8081
```

Properties related to Datasource like url etc. need to be taken from
systems-lookup-service-dev.properties hosted on Git.

```
custom.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1998/smscert
custom.username=smscert
custom.password=go#salt
custom.driverClassName=
```

And the DAO class in config-client accessing the db :

```
public class XXDaoImpl implements XXDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired(required=false)
    private DataSourceConfig config;

    @Autowired
    public SystemDaoImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateIn){
        final DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
                                                        .driverClassName(config.getDriverClassName())
                                                        .url(config.getUrl())
                                                        .username(config.getUsername())
                                                        .password(config.getPassword())
                                                        .build();
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    }
    
    ...............
}


@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("custom")
public class DataSourceConfig {

    private String url;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    //@Value("${greeting.message}")
    private String driverClassName;
    ....
}
```

Comment: An answer provided, if it suits you requirement please consider to upvote and accept it, otherwise feel free to leave comment, i will gladly try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you follow the first boot-strapping for your central cloud registration to do so you need following artifact with in your client service `pom` file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add the following properties to you client service property file `application.prop`

```
spring.application.name=systems-lookup-service
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:"cloud-config-port"
spring.profiles.active=dev
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:
```

With in main class on central cloud config add the annotation `@EnableConfigServer` and within it `pom` file add following artifact

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

append following properties to your central cloud config property file

```
spring.application.name=configuration-server
server.port=8780
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:absoluthe-path
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.cloud.config.allowOverride=true
```

Finally add your client service properties in your gitrepo with naming `servicename-profile` convention.

**Extra point**

You may consider to use spring cloud boss, for hot reloading the configs and not restarting services to handshake again, find out more in [here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-bus).

Comment: Did not understand what is missing in my current property files or code. Or what do I need to do to get rid of the error.

Comment: @kakoli have you seen the 'pom' file dependency ? cause there isnt any 'spring-cloud-config-server' nor 'spring-cloud-starter-config' dependency with in server config and client 'pom' file that you shared.

Comment: Client pom.xml has spring-cloud-starter-config.
Server pom.xml has spring-cloud-config-server

Answer (score -1):

Disabled auto-configuration of the data source by annotating client main with @SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})

Comment: Are you familiar with client side boot-strap approach ? disabling datasource auto-configuration is **not definitely** a solution, the whole problem is about handshaking from server and client to pass environment properties from parent context of IOC to the IOC, which datasource configuration and bean declarations is definitely happens when IOC initiated. completely irrelevant. if you had some thing else in mind about disabling datasource next time try to address is directly https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for saving the time of people who providing answers.

Comment: In this book you can find more insights about client side bootstrap approached Piotr Mińkowski - Mastering Spring Cloud (2018) - page 141 . and getting more familiar with bootstrap context lifecycle and functionalities.